# where can we write windowDidBecomeKey method for MainMenu.xib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i think this is simple question, but i m new to Cocoa. Where can we write -windowDidBecomeKey method for MainMenu.xib, so that when main window becomes the key the method should be invoked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to your app delegate header file, and change something that looks like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
```

to this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>
```

Then go to the implementation file, and implement the method:

```
- (void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // do something
}
```

Then right click on the window's title bar in interface builder and drag the dot next to Delegate onto your app delegate.

---

Alternatively, you can listen to the notification. Add this to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeKey:)
                                             name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification
                                           object:_window];
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can name the listener method whatever you want.